# Java reference storage question

Tags: java, reference

In java, when you pass an object to a method as a parameter, it is actually passing a reference, or a pointer, to that object because objects in Java are references.

Inside the function, it has a pointer to that object which is a location in memory.  I am wondering where this pointer lives in memory?  Is a new memory location created once inside the function to hold this reference?

Comment: "Objects are references" is a very vague and misleading statement. If objects were references, then it would be pointless to distinguish between them, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a function, a parameter reference is stored on the stack. The thing-referenced can live anywhere.

When some code calls a method, what normally happens is that space is made on the executing thread's stack, and this space is used to hold the parameters that are passed to the function. If one of the parameters "is an object", what's really in play is a reference to an object; that reference is copied onto the stack so that the called code can find it. It's important to recognize that the object itself is not copied, just the reference.

The prologue section of the called code will then typically allocate *more* space on the stack, for the method's own local variables, but underneath, the JVM has a pointer to the stack frame with all the parameters, so the called code can locate the object named by the parameter. Items created with 'new' will be allocated from the heap, and can persist even after the method exits, but all items allocated on the stack are dumped simply by moving the stack pointer back to where it was before the call.

Comment: As opposed to being stored on the heap?  I guess I'm also wondering where the reference lives outside of a function call.

Comment: "The thing-referenced can live anywhere" - not true; since it's an object, it lives on the heap.

Comment: @aab: that depends. If its an instance member, it's part of the instance, which lives on the heap. Same for class members and array slots. If it's a local variable, it lives on the stack, just like method parameters.

Comment: @aab if no method or (class) instance is referencing the data anymore, there is no reference. The thing-referenced (the data) may or may not be in heap space, waiting to be garbage collected.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - sorry. Habit from working with RTSJ for a couple of years, in which objects could live in Heap, ImmortalMemory, or various ScopedMemory areas.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not references, but you use references everywhere. e.g.

```
String a = "abc";
```

the `a` is a *reference* to a `String`. So references get passed around everywhere. Are they pointers ? No. A reference is more like a handle to an object. The JVM is at liberty to move around objects within memory. A pointer would have to change to reflect this. A reference doesn't. A reference could be modelled as a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Every parameter of the function is `passed by value` - however, the parameter is not an object, but instead is a reference.

So the same object exists with two references to it.

```
String s = "my string"; // reference to this object created
doSomething(s); // in the doSomething function, a new reference to the same point of memory is passed by value
```

This means when I have my function `void doSomething(String str)` I work the same way as I do outside the function, except I have a different reference. Same object being referenced, but different reference. So if inside my function I do `str = "different string";` that won't change s - s still points to the same point of memory it did the whole time - but now `str` instead of pointing to what s points to, now points to where the "different string" is stored.

Answer (score 0):

for example in JFrame you can start like this:

```
public myFrame mF;

public void Panel1(myFrame mF) {   your code ... }
```